# How to get Local Currency for SKProduct | Display IAP Price in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am trying to display the price of an in app purchase using the local currency, so the correct dollar is displayed for both US & CA as well as Euro, GBP etc.

I know each SKProduct has a price which appears during the transaction as an alert view, this appears when confirming the purchase.

However I want to display the price before confirmation.

I was thinking to do something like this:

```
//Products Array
var productsArray: Array<SKProduct!> = []

//Request Products
    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        if response.products.count != 0 {
            for product in response.products {
                print("\(product.localizedTitle)")
                productsArray.append(product)
            }
        }
        else {
            print("There are no products.")
        }

        if response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count != 0 {
            print("\(response.invalidProductIdentifiers.description)")
        }            
     }


let item = SKProduct
  for i in productsArray {
    if i.localizedTitle == "com.Company.App.item1" 
      item = i
    }
  }
```

But this doesn't work as `i` Doesn't seem to have a price property.

Does anybody know how I can set a label text to the price of an iAP using the correct local currency?

For example £1.49 GBP is $1.99 US dollars using Apples Pricing Matrix and outputting the value should match the values of the product price when confirming the transaction.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Swift 5 and 2021 version:**

Create an extension to SKProduct so you can access `product.localizedPrice` conveniently:

```swift
extension SKProduct {

    private static let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        return formatter
    }()

    var isFree: Bool {
        price == 0.00
    }

    var localizedPrice: String? {
        guard !isFree else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let formatter = SKProduct.formatter
        formatter.locale = priceLocale

        return formatter.string(from: price)
    }

}
```

**Original Anser:**

Swift 4.2 version of Olivier's answer

```
func priceStringForProduct(item: SKProduct) -> String? {
    let price = item.price
    if price == NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 0.00) {
        return "GET" //or whatever you like really... maybe 'Free'
    } else {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        let locale = item.priceLocale
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        numberFormatter.locale = locale
        return numberFormatter.string(from: price)
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware of "localizedPrice" returning unlocalized English strings like "Get".

Answer (score 22):

you should use NSNumberFormatter with the product values for price and priceLocale to output a string that is formatted correctly regardless of the user's location. product.price returns the price in the local currency as an NSDecimalNumber, and product.productLocale returns the NSLocale for the price value.

eg

```
var item = SKProduct()
for i in productsArray {
    if i.productIdentifier == "com.Company.App.item1" {
      item = i
      if let formattedPrice = priceStringForProduct(item) {
        //update ui with price
      }
    } 
 }
```

where priceStringForProduct is function defined elsewhere:-

```
func priceStringForProduct(item: SKProduct) -> String? {
    let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    let price = item.price
    let locale = item.priceLocale
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    numberFormatter.locale = locale
    return numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(price)
}
```

You might also want to handle the special case where the price is 0.0 (free tier). In this case amend the priceStringForProduct function to:

```
func priceStringForProduct(item: SKProduct) -> String? {
    let price = item.price
    if price == NSDecimalNumber(float: 0.0) {
        return "GET" //or whatever you like really... maybe 'Free'
    } else {
        let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        let locale = item.priceLocale
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        numberFormatter.locale = locale
        return numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(price)
    }
}
```

Edit: Couple other things, when you specify your productArray a more 'Swifty' way of doing it is:

```
var productsArray = [SKProduct]()
```

and then in your didRecieveResponse, instead of looping through the products you can just set productsArray as response.products

```
var productsArray = [SKProduct]()
    if response.products.count != 0 {

        print("\(response.products.map {p -> String in return p.localizedTitle})")
        productsArray = response.products

    }
```

Edit: To test for a number of different locales I usually make an array of NSLocales and then loop through printing the result. There is a repo with all the localeIdentifiers's [here](https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273)

so:

```
let testPrice = NSDecimalNumber(float: 1.99)
let localeArray = [NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "uz_Latn"),
    NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_BZ"),
    NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "nyn_UG"),
    NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ebu_KE"),
    NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_JM"),
    NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")]
    /*I got these at random from the link above, pick the countries
    you expect to operate in*/

    for locale in localeArray {
        let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        numberFormatter.locale = locale
        print(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(testPrice))
    }
```

Comment: Ah, yeah you are specifying that you want the SKProduct at index 1 of productsArray, I didn't notice that. basically you've taken the product out of the array and then tried to loop through the product rather than the array. I'll change the code in my answer, just a sec.

Comment: I've changed the loop in my answer, it should work now (hopefully! haha)

Comment: I actually did change it myself to `for i in productsArray` but I think Xcode was being slow. BTW I needed to use `i.productIdentifier` not `i.localizedTitle` as the title is just the name of the iAP. When I changed that it seemed to work. However how can I test this for different locations ?

Comment: I usually make an array of NSLocale's and loop through with a test price. I'll add that to my answer, thank you for marking it correct btw!

Comment: Thanks,this is actually really useful however it just changes the currency type but keeps the value 1.99. I changed `testPrice` with `i.price` and as suspected the item value is the same but the currency changes. This is most likely due to when the product is fetched it already gets the local price value as a number. So it seems there's no way of what the value is going to be in other countries

Comment: Ah yeah you can't change the local price sadly, only see what the format looks like. If I find a way to simulate retrieving a product from a different locale I'll let you know!

Comment: This answer starts well I believe, but goes downhill in the last code snipped. It may induce in error that you can actually do that. Please see the answer from [gnasher729](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40125157/1544047)

Answer (score 12):

Simply  you just need to do the following

```
product.priceLocale.currencyCode
```

Comment: good and short answer

Answer (score 10):

The StoreKit Programming Guide has this code snippet for showing the price using the App Store currency:

```cpp
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
NSString *formattedPrice = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html 
Listing 2-3

Answer (score 6):

You MUST NOT display the price in the local currency. You must display it in the currency provided by the store. If say a French user purchases from the French app store then the price comes up in Euro, and that's what the user pays. If that user goes to New Zealand and changes his or her locale to New Zealand but stays with the French app store, they are still billed in Euros. So that's what you should display.

You say "£1.49 is $1.99 according to Apple's pricing matrix". But £1.49 IS NOT $1.99. If I, as a British user, go to the USA and buy from the UK app store, I pay £1.49 even if I'm in the USA. And "£1.49" is what the store will tell you.

Answer (score 5):

Apple provides `regularPrice` sample code here:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases

```
extension SKProduct {

    /// - returns: The cost of the product formatted in the local currency.
    var regularPrice: String? {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
        return formatter.string(from: self.price)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 version of Olivier's `priceStringForProduct:item`

```
func priceStringForProduct(item: SKProduct) -> String? {
        let price = item.price
        if price == 0 {
            return "Free!" //or whatever you like
        } else {
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            let locale = item.priceLocale
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
            numberFormatter.locale = locale
            return numberFormatter.string(from: price)
        }
    }
```