# Convert NSDecimalNumber to String

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdecimalnumber

How can I convert NSDecimalNumber values to String?

```
// Return type is NSDecimalNumber
var price = prod.minimumPrice // 10

// need a String
cell.priceLB.text = NSString(format:"%f", prod.minimumPrice) as String
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794489/how-to-get-local-currency-for-skproduct-display-iap-price-in-swift

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could try some of these options. They all should return 10. And also check why would you need to create NSString formatting the number and casting it to String.

```
"\(price)"
String(describing: price)
NSString(format: "%@", price)
```

Comment: Also, there is `price.description(withLocale: nil)` which should be used with `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `NumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 8):

NSDecimalValue inherits from NSNumber.

NSNumber have `stringValue` property

```
var stringValue: String { get }

The number object's value expressed as a human-readable string.
The string is created by invoking description(withLocale:) where locale is nil.
```

[Documentation Source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber/1415802-stringvalue)

Answer (score 4):

Two ways:

1. use `NumberFormatter`
2. use `stringValue` property directly

Code using NumberFormatter fixed to two decimal places:

**Swift 5**

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: "1.1")
print(number.stringValue) //"1.1"

 let fmt = NumberFormatter()
  fmt.numberStyle = .none;
  fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
  fmt.minimumIntegerDigits = 1;
  fmt.roundingMode = .halfUp;

let result = fmt.string(from: number) ?? "0.00"  
//1.10
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var price = prod.minimumPrice    
cell.priceLB.text = "\(price)"
//or
cell.priceLB.text = String(describing: price)
```